# find second max salary with lastname in person table?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

```
SELECT  A.LASTNAME ,MAX(SALARY) AS SALARY
FROM PERSONS A
WHERE SALARY<(SELECT MAX(SALARY)
FROM PERSONS)
```

I am getting an error when I run this SQL. I need to get the lastname and salary of the person with the second highest salary.

Comment: You're going to want to use the offset clause http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#BABBADDD

Comment: no i am not use offset clause i want only output sir

Comment: ok, then maybe I don't understand the object of what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `DENSE_RANK()` analytic function:

```
SELECT last_name,
       salary
FROM   (
  SELECT p.*,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY Salary DESC ) AS rnk
  FROM   persons p
)
WHERE  rnk = 2;
```

Comment: but sir i will alreday try but show error at time of run

Comment: SELECT LASTNAME,SALARY FROM PERSONS WHERE SALARY =(SELECT MAX(SALARY) FROM PERSONS ) this show only highest slary only

Comment: If that solution shows an error for you, then you are not using Oracle or you didn't copy the answer as it is shown.

Comment: thank you sir its work but i case duplicate then how to manage

Comment: It will show duplicates if that is what you are after - if not then you will have to restrict it to a single row using whatever criteria you desire. `WHERE ROWNUM = 1` is one option.

Comment: in the above query can i use distanct key

Comment: You can use it in any query ... I do not see how it is helpful unless you have people with the same `last_name` and `salary` and then you would have to think about whether they are duplicates or if they are two people with similar details.

Comment: @ATUL: This query works fine. It shows you the persons with the second highest salary. If you only want one person instead, then it's up to you to define which. You can easily add this criteria to the order by clause, e.g. ` ORDER BY Salary DESC, last_name`. When you have specified the complete ranking order and still get ties and want to pick one tied record arbitarily, then replace `DENSE_RANK` with `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Adding additional criteria to the `ORDER BY` is not going to work. `DENSE_RANK` will assign the same rank in the case of a tie - if you add additional criteria to the `ORDER BY` then you may get rows with the same maximum salary split into different ranks and then this could **not** return the second highest salary but will return the highest salary with the second last name.

Comment: @MT0: You are right. I must be tired. The additional restriction must be done on the main query of course. Anyway, still the first step for ATUL is to define which record to pick in case of a tie :-)

Comment: @MT0 can you help if table have duplicate data so how to remove in the duplicate row in the table persons like i have last name atul 400 salary which is repeat in another row i wnt to remove one row .

Comment: @ATUL If you really do have duplicates you need to remove then, [as you said before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44552206/find-second-max-salary-with-lastname-in-person-table/44552336?noredirect=1#comment76095490_44552336) you can use the `DISTINCT` keyword in the query - but do [consider whether they are actually duplicates or just similar data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44552206/find-second-max-salary-with-lastname-in-person-table/44552336?noredirect=1#comment76095567_44552336).